# Web extensions / plug ins that change the front end of a website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have seen a few WebExtensions and Chrome extensions that change the front end code and add some buttons to that website, for example this one here:

[image: example]

The red button there is not a LinkedIn feature, it came after adding a Chrome extension.

How are they doing it? What are various ways to do this? And what is it exactly called?

Comment: They use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Comment: is that in javascript?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

An extension can, among other things, define Content Scripts ([Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts)).

They are pieces of JavaScript code that execute alongside (but not in the same context as) the webpage code, and more importantly ― have access to the page's DOM.

By modifying the page's DOM, they can add UI elements to the page, whose events are then serviced by the content script's code ― and can trigger actions anywhere else in the extension.

Note that it's the only part of an extension that can modify a page in this way.